# Error updating mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am sending data from an android app to save in my mysql database. 
My Codes are

```
$ress = mysql_query("UPDATE btrack_transaction SET delivery_date = $time, transaction_status = 2 , remark = $rem WHERE transaction_id = $t_id LIMIT 1");
```

And my dabase is as,

`remark varchar(500)    latin1_general_ci`.

The problem is whenever I have $rem as a numbric value then database is updated but if I use any text then it wont.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure wrapping string data with single quote.

```
$ress = mysql_query("UPDATE btrack_transaction SET delivery_date = '$time', transaction_status = 2 , remark = '$rem' WHERE transaction_id = $t_id LIMIT 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Text should be wrapped by single quotes: `''`

```
$ress = mysql_query("UPDATE btrack_transaction SET delivery_date = $time, transaction_status = 2 , remark = '$rem' WHERE transaction_id = $t_id LIMIT 1");
```